# Is it possible to change the original sector size on OLE files?

Tags: document, ole, doc, sector

I tried to change the original sector size on the OLE files(e.g. doc, xls, ppt),
but It is to difficult..

In the documentation, it said that the sector size is 512 bytes.
However, I want to change the size because of my research about document security.

So my question is, "is it possible to reduce the sector size from 512 bytes to 
64 bytes or 128 bytes ?"

Answer (score 0):

is your question related to the Microsoft Teams product? Thinking it isn't, so might want to remove that tag. But if it is, are you wanting to reduce sector size of files in the Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at StgOpenStorageEx(). You can set the sector size in the STGOPTIONS member, but typically the only valid values I remember were 512 and 4096.  Those are probably defined in some header file.  The 512 was for the original implementation and then 4096 was added starting with Windows 2000 which allowed more sub storages in the file.